# Swift hasSuffix method crashing app

Tags: ios, string, swift, crash

I'm trying to detect whether or not a user's input ends with a blank space, and if it does, to remove that space.  I'm using the .hasSuffix() method to see if the space exists, and it should return a boolean variable that I can test for and determine the proper course of action. However, when I check whether the value is true or false, the app crashes.  Any thoughts on why that might be?  Here's the code:

```
var userGuess = userGuessField.text.lowercaseString

var guessEndsWithSpace: Bool = userGuess.hasSuffix(" ")

        // The above will return true if the string ends with a space, so when this happens, remove the space and then check their guess

        if (guessEndsWithSpace == true) {

            println("Guess ends with a space")

            // checkAnswer(userGuess)

        } else {

            println("Guess does not end with a space")
            // Otherwise, just check their guess

            // checkAnswer(userGuess)
```

Comment: what is the type of userGuess? Is it a String! type?

Comment: Worked for me assuming userGuess was a string. Does userGuess have a value?

Comment: @abdullah Yes it's a string, and Bluehound it does have a value, and I've even tried making it optional to see if that was the issue but it still happens

Comment: Perhaps include more code and error messages/logs. There's nothing I see wrong with this and it works like a charm in my playground

Comment: @Bluehound I added the line where I get the user's input and convert it to a lowercase string.  This is the only place I could imagine causing an issue, since userGuess isn't referenced anywhere else in the code.

Comment: "the app crashes" is very vague. If you post the exact error message you're receiving it will help identify your problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure exactly what the issue was, but I went through the code and commented everything out, then uncommented one line at a time and the issue seems to have gone away for the moment.  I have some code left to re-incorporate so I'll see if that causes the issue.